# CSS grid layout: Tag not working on IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-grid

i to search my website on IE Browser to see…

```
<style>
body {
   margin: 5px;
   display: -ms-grid;
   display: grid;
   width: 100%;
   -ms-grid-columns: 9% 73% 17%;
   -ms-grid-rows:  90px 105px 103px 140px 110px 70px;
   background-color: #ebf5d7;
}

body > header {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
  background-image: url("/Bilder/f409784856.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px;
}

body > nav {
 -ms-grid-column: 1;
 -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
 -ms-grid-row: 2;
 margin-top: 30px;
 background-color: #d2f5c4;
}

body > #externalLinks {
   -ms-grid-column: 1;
   -ms-grid-row: 3;
   -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   background-color:  #d2f3c6;
}
body > main {
   -ms-grid-column: 2; 
   -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
   -ms-grid-row: 4;
   background-color: #eaf6e5;
}
body > #furtherInformation {
    -ms-grid-column: 3;
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
    background-color: #d2f3c6;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

body > footer {
        -ms-grid-column: 1;
        -ms-grid-column-span: 6;
        -ms-grid-row: 6;
        background-color: #99ee7a;

}
```

how the screenshot to [show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Svn.png) , all is OK , but when write on my **main** Tag anything, it to show on the Top corner , not to my **main** Tag … i don't know because it not to show .

Can Please anyone help me , Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solve" the problem...people help me  , to found the answer...

with `display: block;` on `body > main{`

```
body > main {
margin: 5px;
grid-area: main;

display: block; 
}
```

Comment: From your last post, It looks like you had solved your issue. I suggest you to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs may help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. Thanks for your understanding

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion , i do it now .I to try yesterday but tell me that i muss to wait 5 hour , and later have it forget...